# I do not know my Minecraft password

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made my Minecraft account about a year ago and I used my dads e-mail. He changed his e-mail and I can't remember my Minecraft password.

How can I retrieve my Minecraft password?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue answered by Mojang Technical Support, not Arqade.SE

Comment: I think that if we can help with that, would be awesome to have some good guidance in here about this

Comment: Well, the only guidance we can really give is, "Contact Mojang".  There's not a whole lot of support we can give related to accounts.  We don't have any way to do anything about users unable to access their accounts.  Maybe have one canonical question about all the problems that require contacting Mojang, and duping all of them to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover my account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278757/how-can-i-recover-my-account)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say ask your dad to help you out first and then change your account to a new e-mail address. Also, please refer to the Mojang FAQ [My email account has changed](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/329530-my-email-account-has-changed-). This link also takes you to the alternate recovery steps since we don't know the type of account you have.

Answer (score 1):

If your Minecraft account was migrated to a Mojang Account, you can request to chance your email address by passing a security challenge.

The page you need is here: https://account.mojang.com/changeemail/request