# How can I recover my account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to log into Minecraft today to find that my password isn't working. I tried to change it, but I can't login to my email because I forgot the answer to my security question. I tried changing the email to a different one, but that didn't work for some reason (it kept saying "invalid email"). I don't have my transation ID because I forgot which credit card I used.

Does this mean that I have to buy a new Minecraft account?

Comment: You could try contacting Mojang support, but if you've lost/forgotten everything that could prove you're the owner of the account, I'm not sure there's much they can do.

Comment: @Joachim we can tell them to contact Mojang. dont see anything wrong with that

Comment: @Joachim feel free to [start a discussion about it if you want](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 4):

There is absolutely nothing anyone here on this site can do to help you. I would recommend contacting [Mojang Support](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/request/new) - they even have an entire section dedicated to account recovery.