# How do I use minecraft when using a new account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I forgot my password and lost access to my email, so I made a new minecraft account. Now all I can play is the demo, how do I play the full game without paying for it again?

Comment: For account issues, you should address mojang's customer service. They should be able to help you out if you have the activation code at hand.

Comment: How did you make a new account without the email/password?  Or did you purchase a second account?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How can I recover my account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278757/how-can-i-recover-my-account)

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 1):

## Contact Customer support

To play the full version of Minecraft, a paid account is necessary. Since November 2012, a Mojang account is the type of account used to play Minecraft.

Here is an overview of the different account types and what is used to log into Minecraft:

> ## Mojang Account
>
> Currently, all Minecraft: Java Edition purchases are attached to a Mojang account.
>   You have registered a Mojang account and log into account.mojang.com with your email address.
>   After you make your purchase, you can select a Minecraft username and log into the game.
>
> If you created a Minecraft account prior to November 2012, the following may apply to you:
>
> ### Mojang Account (migrated from Minecraft account)
>
> You have migrated your paid Minecraft account to a Mojang account.
>   You use your email address to log into Minecraft and Mojang services.
>   You no longer log into Minecraft and minecraft.net with a username.
>
> ### Minecraft account - paid (formerly known as premium)
>
> You have purchased a copy of Minecraft from Minecraft.net.
>   You use your Minecraft username to log into Minecraft services, and can access the full game.
>   You can reset the password and migrate the account to a Mojang account by visiting account.mojang.com/migrate.
>
> ### Minecraft account - unpaid
>
> You have previously registered a Minecraft username but did not purchase the game.
>   You use your Minecraft username to log into Minecraft services, but are unable to use services other than demo mode.
>   These accounts were deleted in February 2015, and the usernames were made available to all, except those accounts that had purchased a gift code.

If your old, paid account is a Mojang account, then access to the E-Mail address will be necessary to recover your password.

If you have any documents that show that you bought the game (receipt with the transaction ID, or the gift code, if the game was gifted to you), you could try contacting Mojang Customer Support to try and retrieve the Mojang account and change the associated E-Mail address.