# Minecraft Loginh issues on both website and launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So im using a minecraft account that i have no access to the email whatsover however i know the email and password. I have logged in before and played minecraft normally. However, suddenly today I was logged out of the launcher and my password would not work in the launcher. i kept getting the error Invalid Email or Password. is there anyway of me regaining access as it wont work at the minecraft.net website either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover my account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278757/how-can-i-recover-my-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You WILL need the purchase ID - it's in the receipt email you got when buying the game. With the purchase ID, you can contact the support from a working email address, explain that you don't have access to your old email, and ask to have the account moved to the current email address. It's a lengthy process (~1 month) but eventually your account will be associated with an address you can access. At this point you use the 'reset password' link accessible when logging in, then set a new password which you can then use to log in.

Without the purchase ID and without access to the email address associated with your account, the situation is pretty much hopeless - there's nothing to prove "you're you" and that you aren't a hacker trying to hijack an account of a legit customer through social engineering. At that point your best option is to create a new account (linked to a valid email address that is unlikely to vanish in the future) and re-purchase the game.