# Minecraft name changed + Lost access to account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I forgot what Microsoft account was attached to my Minecraft account please help!
Lost access and it seems like it was maybe changed because my name changed to DontBhopPlz

Comment: How much of [this process](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/you-forgot-your-microsoft-account-username-b2049472-3b8f-27d3-61c6-67a668453f4c) have you tried already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover my account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278757/how-can-i-recover-my-account)

Comment: All of it @Kevin